# Adding Constant to resources

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a brush defined as a constant in code that I want to add to the resources tag of a DataGrid I have defined in XAML with a specific key.

How do I do this?

I need to add the existing brush with the key since Im overriding the look of a highlighted row:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
 <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
   <GradientStop Color="#FFD6A4" Offset="0"/>
   <GradientStop Color="#FFAB3F" Offset="1"/>
 </LinearGradientBrush>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

The brush I want to use without having to redefine it is:

```
public static class Colours
{
  public static LinearGradientBrush HighlightedRow { get; private set; }
  static Colours()
  {
    HighlightedRow = new LinearGradientBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 214, 164), Color.FromRgb(255, 171, 63), 90);
  }
}
```

Comment: Pls write your code so I can see what you want to achieve. Maybe a possibke solution is DataBinding to the Viewmodel

Comment: Why do you want to put it in your resources? Can you not just bind to it?

Comment: There is no HighlightBrush property to bind to, hence that key needs to be overridden in the resources on the DataGrid

Comment: @MagnusAhlin How do you access the Brush? I imagine in your DataGrid's ItemTemplate. It should be possible to use binding there. Please show us the code, that actually uses the HighghlitBrushKey.

Comment: There is no code or xaml that is using the brush. That key is what the internals of the DataGrid use to find what brush to use for rendering the highlighted row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in code behind:

```
myDataGrid.Resources.Add(SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey, Colours.HighlightedRow);
```

Or in XAML only:
If you had the two gradient stop colors as resources, then you could reference them dynamically in XAML.

```
<Color x:Key="Color1">#FFFF0000</Color>
<Color x:Key="Color2">#FFFF3300</Color>
<DataGrid.Resources>
 <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
  <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource Color1}" Offset="0"/>
 <GradientStop Color="{DynamicResource Color2}" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I had hoped I would have been able to do this in XAML though.

Comment: Oooh, my bad. I understood it the other way around. :) If you had the two gradient stop colors as resources, then you could reference them dynamically in XAML. I've updated my answer. Hope that helps.